# Does wp_mail work in frontend tempate file?

Tags: templates

I am creating a function in a template that will send an email using wp_mail function.

My question is if it can be used be not logged in users or not.

I mean directly from a template file like (it's just an example, in my real example it's much more code):

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Custom Template
 *
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php


    $headers = 'From: Tester 1 <testmail@something.com>' . "\r\n";
    $subject = 'Subject test' . "\r\n";
    $message = 'Just a test stuff.';
    wp_mail('testmail@something.com', $subject, $message, $headers );


?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If not, how can I simulate logged in user just for this thing?

It's not working for me right now, so I was thinking that I need soem more permission maybe?

Comment: Are you testing locally?

Comment: @G.M. No, on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if it can be used be not logged in users or not.

Yes. `wp_mail()` works fine from the front end when not logged in. I use it for a contact page on my web site.